# Launching touch events programmatically

Tags: codenameone

In my App I need to fire a touch event programmatically at a specific position on the device screen.
How can I do this in CodeName One Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke:

```
Form f = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
f.pointerPressed(x, y);
f.pointerReleased(x, y);
```

Comment: Thank you Shai.
The simplicity is impressive.